# How to figure out whether a nonlinear inequality holds or not

Tags: equation-solving

I have an inequality consisted only of seven parameters as follows:

$(1 + g)^{-(m+w)}\big[\big\{a+(1-a)(1 + g)^m\big\}(1 + p q)Q - (1 + g)^w \big\{(1 + g)^m (1 + q)-(1-p)q\big\} Q\big] < 0$

Parameters, $g$, $w$, and $m$, are subject to the following restrictions:

$0<g$, $0<w$, $0<m$, $0<Q$

That is, these four parameters are all positive.

Now, we can manually verify that this inequality holds under the above parameter restrictions. And I would like to confirm this with Mathematica.

My codes for the assumptions:

```
$Assumptions = 0 < g && 0 < w && 0 < m && 0 < Q
```

And as for checking if the inequality holds, I used `Refine` and `If` as follows:

```
Refine[If[(1 + g)^(-m - w) ((a - (-1 + a) (1 + g)^m) (1 + p q) Q - (1 + g)^w ((-1 + p) q + (1 + g)^m (1 + q)) Q)<0, Print[True], Print[False]]]
```

Since the condition is true, the result I expect is `True`. But what I get is a simple repetition of the `If` bracket:

```
If[(1 + g)^(-m - w) ((a - (-1 + a) (1 + g)^m) (1 + p q) Q - (1 + g)^w ((-1 + p) q + (1 + g)^m (1 + q)) Q) < 0, Print[Yes], Print[No]]
```

When I use a little simpler, but similar, type of inequality, it gives me either `True` or `False` depending on the specific form of inequality I use. But it seems Mathematica is not able to figure out whether the above inequality, which is too complex (maybe?), is true or false.

Or am I missing something? Can anyone help? Thank you so much.

Comment: I couldn't get it to `Refine` either, but I expect that part of the answer will be that you need to also tell Mma that pk, q, and Q are Real (and not Complex), since comparison with zero isn't well-defined for complex numbers.

Comment: PS. You don't need the `If` and `Print` statements.  If `Refine` works it will return `True`!

Comment: I don't think this inequality is true.  Try, for example, the values

`{g -> 0.001, m -> 0.001, w -> 0.001, Q -> -10^7, a -> 1, p -> 1, 
 q -> 1}`.

Then the LHS gives 39.98, which is more than 0.  So I think you have some unstated assumptions.

Comment: @evanb Oh yes, you are right. One missing assumption is $Q>0$. I will add this right away!

Comment: Sorry, that's still not enough.  Try `{g -> 0.01, m -> 0.01, w -> 0.01, Q -> 1, p -> -10^8, a -> 0.01,  q -> 0.01}`

Comment: Also: Mma doesn't need to know anything about `a` and `q` to `Refine[w*m > 0]` if it knows, via `$Assumptions` that `w` and `m` are positive!  Try instead Refine[a*w*m>0].  That fails to refine.

Comment: @evanb Yes you are right. In fact, I should set all the symbolic arguments are positive real. But this is the issue. Regardless of the direction of the inequality, I would like Mma to tell me which one is correct, without me calculating all this manually.

Comment: @evanb I added an assumptions telling Mma that all the symbolic variables are real. But the result is the same. It seems the problem lies elsewhere. When I do Refine[w*m > 0] without telling Mma that `w` and `m` are real, it gives me the correct result True

Comment: When I `Refine[w m > 0]` it simply returns `w m > 0`.  I expect you have not cleared $Assumptions.

Comment: The inequality simply is not true, even with the assumption that all the symbols are positive and real.  Try, for example, `{Q -> 10^10, q -> 10^-7, w -> 10^-7, g -> 10^-8, a -> 10^-7, p -> 10^10, m -> 10^-5}` and I can make the answer arbitrarily large by increasing `Q`.

Comment: @evanb Thanks so much for the followup. As I mentioned above, the direction of the inequality is not my concern. Ok, as you said, let us have the opposite direction of inequality. Now I would like to confirm that with Mathematica. Again, thank you so much!

Comment: `FindInstance` is a good function to check for existence of a counterexample. `FindInstance[(1 + g)^(-m - w) ((a - (-1 + a) (1 + g)^m) (1 + p q) Q - (1 + g)^w ((-1 + p) q + (1 + g)^m (1 + q)) Q) < 0 && 0 < g && 0 < w && 0 < m && 0 < Q, {g, w, m, Q, p, a, q}]` gives one quite quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html) instead of `Refine`.  Also, you might as well cancel the factors `(1+g)^(-m-w)` and `Q` which are positive.  Then, since `g > 0` and `m` and `w` are independent positive real numbers, we may as well replace

```
{(1 + g)^m -> u, (1 + g)^w -> v}
```

to simplify its human readability.  The conditions translate to `u > 1` and `v > 1`.  The inequality becomes

```
expr = ((a - (-1 + a) (1 + g)^m) (1 + p q) - (1 + g)^w ((-1 + p) q + (1 + g)^m (1 + q)))  /.
  {(1 + g)^m -> u, (1 + g)^w -> v}
(* (1 + p q) (a - (-1 + a) u) - ((-1 + p) q + (1 + q) u) v *)
```

Then we can use `Reduce`, with or without specifying the order of the variables.

```
Assuming[a > 0 && p > 0 && q > 0 && u > 1 && v > 1,
 Reduce[$Assumptions && expr < 0]
 ]
(*
  v > 1 && (
    (0 < a < 1 && (
       (1 < u <= (a - v)/(-1 + a) && p > 0 && q > 0) ||
       (u > (a - v)/(-1 + a) && (
          (0 < p <= (v - u v)/(-a - u + a u + v) && q > 0) ||
          (p > (v - u v)/(-a - u + a u + v) && 
             0 < q < (a + u - a u - u v)/(-a p - p u + a p u - v + p v + u v)))))
     ) ||
    (a >= 1 && u > 1 && p > 0 && q > 0))
*)
```

The order of the variables matters (because `Reduce` will return a cylindrical decomposition).  You can play with it to see if one makes the problem clearer.

```
Assuming[a > 0 && p > 0 && q > 0 && u > 1 && v > 1,
 Reduce[$Assumptions && expr < 0, {p, q, a, u, v}]
 ]
(*
  (0 < p <= 1 && q > 0 && a > 0 && u > 1 && v > 1) ||
  (p > 1 && q > 0 && (
     (0 < a < (-q + p q)/(1 + p q) && u > 1 &&
          v > (a + a p q + u - a u + p q u - a p q u)/(-q + p q + u + q u)) ||
     (a >= (-q + p q)/(1 + p q) && u > 1 && v > 1)))
*)
```

One can also play with the alternative inequality to understand why it is not simply true or false.

```
Assuming[a > 0 && p > 0 && q > 0 && u > 1 && v > 1,
 red = Reduce[$Assumptions && expr > 0]
 ]
(*
  v > 1 && 0 < a < 1 && u > (a - v)/(-1 + a) && 
    p > (v - u v)/(-a - u + a u + v) && 
    q > (a + u - a u - u v)/(-a p - p u + a p u - v + p v + u v)
*)
```

Interpreting this, it says we can pick any `v > 1` and `0 < a < 1`.  Let's do this and examine `red`:

```
red /. {v -> 2, a -> 1/2} // Simplify
(* u > 3 && 4 + p (-3 + u) > 4 u && 1 + q (4 + p (-3 + u) - 4 u) > 3 u *)
```

Now we can pick any `u > 3`:

```
red /. {v -> 2, a -> 1/2, u -> 4} // Simplify
(* p > 12 && q > 11/(-12 + p) *)
```

Next, pick `p > 12`:

```
red /. {v -> 2, a -> 1/2, u -> 4, p -> 13} // Simplify
(* q > 11 *)
```

And finally pick `q > 12`:

```
red /. {v -> 2, a -> 1/2, u -> 4, p -> 13, q -> 12} // Simplify
(* True *)
```

So the settings `{v -> 2, a -> 1/2, u -> 4, p -> 13, q -> 12}` make the expression positive:

```
expr /. {v -> 2, a -> 1/2, u -> 4, p -> 13, q -> 12}
(* 1/2 *)
```

Similarly one can find numbers that make the expression negative.  [@evanb](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/7936/evanb) has pointed some of this out in comments.

Comment: thank you so much for your help. I wasn't able to interpret the results of the third and fourth code. Do you know what these mean? It seems, with these you are saying that we cannot tell whether my inequality is true or not. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @jim I think that very last command gives conditions for which the inequality is false.  Just find values of the variables which make the reduced inequalities true.  From the second last command, the condition `(0 < p <= 1 && q > 0 && a > 0 && u > 1 && v > 1)` shows at least some range for the variables over which the inequality is true.  I'll add something to the last one to clarify.

Comment: It really help! Thank you! Can I ask you one more question? What do we mean by 'order' here?

Comment: @jim Whether you list the variables in the order `{p, q, a, u, v}` or `{a, q, u, p, v}` or any other order.  The order determines how the inequality is broken down.  With `{p, q, a, u, v}`, you first have a `p` inequality, `&&` then a `q`, `&&` then `a`, etc.  Different cases are connected with `Or` (`||`).  With `{a, q, u, p, v}`, it would start with an `a` inequality.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot! I really appreciate!

Comment: @jim You're welcome.